# Error code 183 from CreateToolhelp32Snapshot

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit

This seems like it would be a reasonably common issue, but I've been unable to find a clear answer, so here goes:

I have two processes running on Windows Server 2008 x64. Both processes are 64-bit. 
Process A is run by a user with Administrator role, Process B is run by a user with Standard role.

Process B tries to get a list of the dlls loaded by Process A by calling CreateToolhelp32Snapshot with the TH32CS_SNAPMODULE flag and the pid of Process A.

The call to CreateToolhelp32Snapshot fails with error code 183 and GetLastError gives me: "Cannot create a file when that file already exists".

Is this simply a permissions problem because Process B is not running as admin?  In this case I would have expected the ACCESS_DENIED error. 
If anyone can shed any light on the reason for this error, and/or suggest a solution or workaround, it would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Your error handling is broken, we can't see you doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks Hans... so you're saying it should work, yes? The admin user/standard user shouldn't have an impact, is that correct?

Comment: No, he's saying that you're doing something wrong but we can't tell you what it is, because you haven't posted your code. We can't possibly debug code to explain why it doesn't work if you don't include it in your question, because we can't see your screen from where we're sitting.